# Strategies for a clustered Spring Integration Application

Tags: spring-integration

Wanted to put a broader question around about how to best manage a clustered Spring Integration application behind a LB typically a AWS ALB for instance .

1. **Leader Election** : This is supported with SI with roles and leader election apis  https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#leadership-event-handling and I guess it has good support as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/zookeeper.html .
2. **Managing adapters in the cluster** . Right now we expose a few rest api's to start stop specific SI adapters/message handlers . But these are typically in each node , is there a way we can somehow register these at a common store and then provide common interfaces to manage and discover them .THis will enable actions to be applied across the whole cluster and discover adapters across all nodes .
3. **Load Balancing Adapters** : How to load balance adapters across varioud nodes . This is typically usefull when say we spawn ftp,http,jms adapters dynamically in SI .

Do let me know your thoughts

Comment: dead link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#leadership-event-handling

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into Spring Cloud Bus project: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR3/#_spring_cloud_bus:

> Spring Cloud Bus links nodes of a distributed system with a lightweight message broker. This can then be used to broadcast state changes (e.g. configuration changes) or other management instructions.

Comment: Ya this would help in pushing start stop events for same adapters , but I guess for load balancing adapters we would still need something custom like a registry to register adapters and then auto-balance them like it happens for nodes in a load balancer .

Comment: Well, for auto-balancing we really have that mentioned roles and leader election

Comment: Yup great I guess this applies to dynamic Integration Flows as well as they are instances of SmartLifeCycle ...